# Is there a way to have an inner CSS table expand the full width of an outer CSS table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I've built a table using the CSS display: table, display: table-row, and display: table-cell method. However, when I attempt to use a table within that table, for a smaller subsection of data within the larger data, I cannot get the inner table to expand the full width of its parent table.

```
<div class="table clearfix">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-row">
    <div class="inner-row-container">
      <div class="table clearfix">
        <div class="head">
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/hitokage/pen/qBZJbpG

I know that there is no such thing as colspan with CSS tables, and any method I've attempted has resulted in failure. I cannot close off the parent table before the inner table due to looping within the code.

Comment: Why use a CSS table when you can use the `table` element? as long as you're using it for tabley things, it should be fine to use them (even in html5)

Comment: There were other items we were doing within the table we found to be very frustrating at times with the table element, and were looking into other possibilities. The display: table table worked perfectly for our needs, minus this one odd, frustrating issue.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of colspan/rowspan is just one of the limitations of display:table Another potential approach is to use flexbox to fake your table, benefits being additional control when the page goes responsive as well.

```css
.table {
    width: 100%;
  
}
.table .head, .table .row {
  display:flex;

}
.table .head, .table .row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.table .inner-row {
  padding: 20px;
  background:#cfcfcf;
}

.table .inner-row .table {
  border:1px solid black;
}

.table .inner-row .table .row {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cell {
  flex-basis: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table clearfix">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-row">
    <div class="inner-row-container">
      <div class="table clearfix">
        <div class="head">
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
          <div class="cell">inner stuff</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
    <div class="cell">stuff</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```